# Votes cast using stack exchange app not reflected on web-site votes cast count

Tags: bug, voting, android-app

Today I've casted a few votes in Stack Overflow using Stack Exchange android app (around 10 votes, I was actually looking for the Winterbash-2015 Wireless hat and I earned it). But when I switched to the Stack Overflow web-site and checked my profile the Votes Cast for the day shown as 1. (Actually that one vote was casted earlier today from the web-site itself). I think the votes I casted using stack exchange app is not reflected in the count and seems like a bug to me, please correct me If I'm wrong or I'm missing anything here.

Comment: I cast some votes about 10 minutes ago and they're reflected on my profile page.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: My page also got updated but after 1 hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it seems to me the vote count is cached. This is done to prevent massive loads on the database. I just voted on the web site and the number doesn't increment, while both votes I casted (one from the iOS app, which uses the same API, another from the web site) are visible in the *votes* tab.

I think you should wait a little longer, maybe half an hour or so, in order to see the vote count corrected.

Comment: It's already 1 hour and  I tried refresh several times, it didn't update the data. Let's wait some more time. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I voted 8 and 10 minutes ago and now it updated my view. The number is now correct here.

Comment: My page got updated after 1 hour

Comment: Okay. Glad it is fixed this way.